# Use of undeclared type Error when trying to conform to WCSessionDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit, xcode8

I am using Xcode 8. I am also using Swift 2.3 with the legacy build setting set to yes. I am not migrating to Swift 3 at the moment. My app is targeting iOS 9.3. I am targeting watchOS 2.0.

I have two classes conforming to WCSessionDelegate that worked just fine in Xcode 7.3.1.

I looked at the apple documentation and saw that there is required methods for this protocol now, namely the one I seem to need is this one:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, 
   error: Error?)
```

I get the error: `Use of undeclared type 'Error'`

I think Error is introduced as of Swift 3? Not sure but since I am on swift 2.3 I cannot conform to the method and I am confused on how to fix this. Adding to my confusion is the error claiming I do not conform to the protocol goes away by putting the function in the class...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Working with Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8 would force you a bunch of efforts, Xcode 8 may suggest Swift 3 version of method templates, Apple does not provide Swift 2 version of references...

To implement delegate method in Swift 2.3, you need check the Objective-C version of the method and think how Swift 2 imports it by yourself.

[session:activationDidCompleteWithState:error:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsessiondelegate/1615679-session?language=objc)

> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> - (void)session:(WCSession *)session 
> activationDidCompleteWithState:(WCSessionActivationState)activationState
>           error:(NSError *)error;
> ```

Nullability annotations are often omitted in the reference, so you better check the actual .h header for the delegate...

### WCSession.h

```
/** Called when the session has completed activation. If session state is WCSessionActivationStateNotActivated there will be an error with more details. */
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session activationDidCompleteWithState:(WCSessionActivationState)activationState error:(nullable NSError *)error __IOS_AVAILABLE(9.3) __WATCHOS_AVAILABLE(2.2);
```

So, the method header in Swift 2 would be like this:

```
func session(session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWithState activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: NSError?)
```

---

I recommend you to continue using Xcode 7 to work with Swift 2 if you have no need to use new iOS10/watchOS3 features in your app. (You can submit apps built with Xcode 7 as for now.) Or else you'd better migrate your app to Swift 3 (I know it may take far more than "a bunch of efforts" in many cases...) if you expect some help from Xcode or the latest reference.

Comment: Does an app made in xcode 7.3 with a target of iOS 9.3 work on iOS 10 though?

Comment: @danielx0328, of course, if your app does not use some removed-in-iOS10 features. Just that testing on iOS 10 sims/devices with Xcode 7 would be a little bit difficult. Target setting is just designating the minimum iOS version.

Comment: Thats my problem, i dont know if ios 10 features broke my app. It runs on ios 9 but not 10. So i want to debug it in ios 10 simulator and need Xcode 8 for that :/

Comment: @danielx0328, I know we should test our apps with all targeted devices. One way, you make your app almost complete in Xcode 7, test it thoroughly with iOS9.3 sims/devices, and after that, convert the project to Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8. There may not be much work needed than testing with iOS10 sims/devices, as you know, so many apps made for iOS9 still work in iOS 10 devices.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm to `WCSessionDelegate` Protocol in swift 2.3 Xcode 8, You should implement these three methods:

```
func session(session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWithState activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: NSError?){
}

func sessionDidBecomeInactive(session: WCSession) {        
}

func sessionDidDeactivate(session: WCSession) {        
}
```